# resuming animation after onPause () android - java

Tags: java, android, animation

just simple question I have an  animation where I should put them ?  in On-create or in On-resume or where ? so that when I pause the activity the animation is paused .. not played in background !  and when I resume the Activity the animation resumes .. not start from zero !    ?

my animation is like that :

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide);
```

Comment: Do you know how to pause/resume the animation?

Comment: You should probably start the animation in Activity.onStart and pause it in Activity.onStop. An activity is considered visible/started once onStart has been called

Comment: I have read how to pause and resume animation using Animator .. so should I convert all my animation to Animator .. and it only supports minSdkVersion 19 !